# Clone object with limited sub-objects in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a object as below -

```
var product = [{name:"laptop", price:"10000", avail:true},
{name:"keyboard", price:"500", avail: true},
{name:"bt mouse", price:"999", avail: false}];
```

This needs to be cloned to another object with limited properties.

> expected output

```
onlyProduct = [{name:"laptop",avail:true},
    {name:"keyboard",avail:true},
    {name:"bt mouse",avail:false}];
```

I have tried to clone with extend, but it give a true copy

```
var onlyProduct = $.extend(true,{},product)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requirement mainly calls for a different approach like this:

```
var onlyProduct = []

// Loop through the main product array
$.each(product, function (i, n) {

    // Push the required properties in the new onlyProduct array
    onlyProduct.push({
        name: n.name,
        avail: n.avail
    });
});

// View the new array in browser console
console.log(onlyProduct);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newProduct = [];
for (i in product){
    newProduct[i] = {};
    for (j in product[i]){
        if(j != 'price'){
            newProduct[i][j] = product[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

[DEMO JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ArtyukhAlex/np6saztx/) check in console

Comment: onlyProduct is the expected outpcome. Also i miss the $ power in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `delete`

```
var product = [{name:"laptop", price:"10000", avail:true},
{name:"keyboard", price:"500", avail: true},
{name:"bt mouse", price:"999", avail: false}];

var backup = product;

for (counter = 0; counter <product.length; counter++) {
  delete product[counter]['price'];
}

console.log(product);
```